# Twilio - create a conversation service or a conversation user the node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-conversations

I am trying to create a new conversation service resource in Twilio and to add a new conversation client to it. I am trying the node.js example but I don't have the option that the documentation shoes.

So for creating a new conversation Service I found this document: [image]

But it seems that I can't create a conversation Service and can't create a user resource. I don't have an autocompletion for it and even if I try to ignore the IDE warning and to hardcode the command I am getting the error = "can't read create of undefined". You can see the marker that I got under the "services" word. This is also happening for user resource under the word "users". All the other commands (like create a conversation) are available.

[image]

Comment: Can you share full source code with instantiation and how you set up your project? When you say "commands are available" does this mean they work? What Twilio version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I just tested with the latest version of the [Twilio Node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio), which is 3.57.0 as of today. Twilio libraries are released every 2 weeks with new features. I was able to make the call to create a new Conversations service.

I would try upgrading the Twilio version and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you so much @pholnash. Where you also enable to create new user. I got an underline mark under the  users word in client.users

Comment: @UdiMazor make sure you are always using the conversations resource. So you should be creating users with `client.conversations.users.create(opts)` or, if you specify the service, `client.conversations.services(serviceSid).users.create(opts)`.